# Testing existence of Eloquent relationship and creating if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What would be the best way to create a relationship if it doesn’t exist already, within Eloquent, or at least a central location.

This is my dilemma. A `User` must have a `Customer` model relationship. If for whatever reason that customer record doesn’t exist (some bug that stopped it from being created) - I don’t want it to throw errors when I try to retrieve it, but I also request the customer object in multiple locations so I don’t want to test for existence in all those places.

I thought of trying the following in the `User` model:

```
public function getCustomerAttribute($value) {
        // check $value and create if null
    }
```

But that doesn’t work on relationships, `$value` is `null`.

**EDIT**

I already create a customer upon user creation, but I have come across a situation where it wasn't created and caused exceptions in many places, so I want to fallback.

```
User::created(function($user) {
           $customer = Customer::create([
               'user_id' => $user->id
           ]);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to assume when a user is created that a customer needs to be created as well? If the rest of your system depends on this assumption I would make a model event.

```
use App\{User, Customer}; // assuming php7.0

UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Boot
     */
     public function boot()
     {
        // on a side note, we're using "created" not "creating" because the $user->id needs to exist in order to save the relationship.
        User::created(function($user) {
           $customer = Customer::create([
               'user_id' => $user->id
           ]);
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's correct, I have that set up already. I've just come across a situation where a customer wasn't created automatically, for whatever reason I don't know. So I'm wondering the best place to safeguard against that incase I try to retrieve the customer and it's null.

Comment: 2 things.

1. Write a console command/migration to create those missing customer objects.
2. In the `getCustomerAttribute()` accessor test for `if(is_null($this->customer()->first()));` and throw a custom exception like `MissingCustomerObject` then catch it accordingly.

Comment: Great thank you. I was hoping for an "official" way but if there's nothing like this built into Laravel then I will have to do one of those.

Comment: Nope! Not as far as I'm aware of. Active Record is very DIY like that.